# Optimal placement of figures

Tags: optimization, packing-problem

I have to place **8 copies** of the following figure

[image: figure]

on a piece of paper with a width of $90$ cm.

The question is how should I place the figures in order to use the least amount of paper?

Here is my try (by trial and error) but can it be done any better? (The $x$-coordinate of the right-most point is approximately $91{,}81$.)

[image: output]

It is an exam question from 2019 from the Danish secondary school system. I'm a teacher and the only motivation is that I would like to show the best possible solution for my students.

Comment: I think this question seems out of blue. What are the motivation for this question?

Comment: @RounakSarkar: The asker clarified that it is from an exam question where students are awarded points based on how good their solution is. By the way, I'd mention for reference that such problems are generally known as packing problems and they are typically extremely difficult (e.g. till today the known solution for packing 11 squares in a square is still not proven optimal according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_packing_in_a_square)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a much better solution that fits within a $9×8.61$ sheet (with each unit being $10\text{ cm}$). I have good reason to think it is optimal but who knows...

[image: Screenshot of Geogebra showing the solution]

The idea was to pack 4 kites into the left half that has height $9$ and width roughly $4.5$, except that the lower part juts out by a bit to the right while the upper part has leftover space on the right, and then rotate the left half by 180° to get the right half.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I kept moving it around by hand until it fit... I actually had some angle measurements to check that N and O are strictly above the lower pieces, but I deleted the measurements off before taking the screenshot. As you probably know, I used a tool to draw each piece (e.g. A,B are the input points for the piece with points A,C,D,E).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Thanks, and you're welcome! My first few attempts were inferior to your configuration, and I thought of the rotation trick only after those failures. =)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Well, based on just eye-balling it, it looks like it would involve a cubic equation. Do you really want to go that far? =)

Comment: Thanks for helping me.